# Restlet consume post webservice, add json-string as representation

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restlet

I want to consume a rest webservice using restlet. This will be done with a post. 
What do I need to add to the following code:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("url");      
resource.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, user, password);
```

I have a Json string and in the code where my rest-webservice is implemented the input is an Representation object. I need my parameter to be(being the jsonstring) in the enitity.gettext() method if possible.

```
public StartProcessInstanceResponse startProcessInstance(Representation entity)
jsonstring = entity.gettext();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself...
You should make a Represenation object like this

```
Representation rep = new StringRepresentation(jsonString);
```

Then you can post like this:

```
resource.post(rep);
```

That's it...